# File gets replaced in opencart using VQmod

Tags: php, opencart2.x, vqmod

I have been working in opencart which contains VQmod in that I have faced the following problem. I did changes in `view file (tpl)` and its working fine in localhost. After Uploading to live server, the changes which I made are in the view file, but The site displays the old changes because of VQmod. How to solve the Issue?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You don't need to highlight your question as a quote.

Comment: Do you use any module which is using OC mod? If you are using only VQmod then try to clear VQcache files and then check

Comment: is it possible that vqmod is not installed in live site. or pls clear the cache